# How to write fast for loops with numpy for implicit methods

Tags: python, numpy, numeric

Numpy is excellent for speeding up code by vectorization. However, when doing for example implicit, iterative equation solving methods like the [Gauss-Seidel method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method), then element `n+1` of the array depend on the `n` first elements, preventing vectorization.

I have implemented gauss-seidel like this:

```py
def gaussSeidel(A, b, x0, tol = 1e-10):
    n = len(A)
    x = np.copy(x0)
    k = 0

        while (True):
        print(k)
        for i in range(n):
            x[i] = (b[i] - np.delete(A[i], i) @ np.delete(x, i)) / A[i, i]

        if max(abs(x - x0)) < tol:
            return x

        x0 = np.copy(x)
        k += 1
```

This way slower than an explicit version, like the Jacobi method,

```py
def jacobi(A, b, x0, tol = 1e-10):
    n = len(A)
    M = np.copy(A)
    DInv = np.zeros((n, n))
    k = 0
    for i in range(n):
        DInv[i, i] = 1 / M[i, i]
        M[i, i] = 0

    while (True):
        x = DInv @ (b - M @ x0)
        if max(abs(x - x0))  < tol:
            return x
        x0 = x
        k += 1
        print(max(abs(x - x0)))
```

As far as i know, it isn't possible to eliminate the for loop here, but is it a way to speed it up?

Comment: You can vectorise the inner `for` loop ... that’s effectively a dot product omitting the *i-th* element ... so use a full dot product and adjust it accordingly

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the code, and it helps some, but the main problem still persists

Comment: Can you add sample data, which is relevant for you. What is the array shape of A,b,x0?

Comment: The esaence of numpy vectorization is to move the loops to compiled code - in the whole-array methods.

Comment: Earlier I suggested using a dot product and adjusting to remove the inner loop ... using `numpy.delete` to do so is **not** a good approach to this as it will cause a copy.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help somewhat, is moving the if-test outside of following loop

```
        s = b[i]
        for j in range(n):
            if i == j:
                continue
            s -= A[i, j] * x[j]
```

as in

```
        s = b[i] + A[i, i] * x[i]
        for j in range(n):
            s -= A[i, j] * x[j]
```

That way n if-tests are avoided.

Another thing to try out is the [numba](https://numba.pydata.org) package, which can compile your code on the fly without the overhead of an external compilation step.